# Avoid three for-in loops to compute values

Tags: swift, algorithm, refactoring, for-in-loop

Supposed I have these objects which are nested :

```
struct Order {
    let ref: Int
    let starters: [Starter]
    let formatedDate: String
    var status: Int?
}

struct Starter {
    let subEntries: [SubEntry]
}

struct SubEntry {
    let status: Int
    let id_Dish: Int
}
```

I need to make some operations to filter some elements and at this moment I only manage to make it by using 3 for in loops as below :

```
func computeStatus(openOrders: inout [Order]) {
    for openOrder in openOrders {
        for entry in openOrder.starters {
            outerLoop: for subEntry in entry.subEntries {
                if subEntry.id_Dish == 0 {
                    print("\(openOrder.ref) is canceled")
                    break outerLoop
                }
                if !entry.subEntries.filter({ $0.status < 16 }).isEmpty {
                    print("\(openOrder.ref) is waiting")
                    break outerLoop
                } // waiting
                if entry.subEntries.filter({ $0.status == 0 }).isEmpty && entry.subEntries.filter({ $0.status == 16}).count >= 1  {
                    print("\(openOrder.ref) is in production")
                    break outerLoop
                }
                if entry.subEntries.allSatisfy({$0.status == 255 }) {
                    print("\(openOrder.ref) is ready")
                    break outerLoop
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

How can I refactor this code and avoid the multiple loops ?

Comment: You can't do anything about the first 2 loops.  For the third, it looks like you break out as soon as you find an entry to report on.  Will any entries exist that won't fulfil these conditions?  If so, then it will always report on the first entry only... meaning it might make sense to only store one entry at that level.

Comment: You can write different functions for each level and call them nested.